# Android Implementation of WebView (postURL)

Tags: android, post, webview, get

I am researching the method [WebView#postUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#postUrl(java.lang.String,%20byte[])) in 4.3; the description says:

> If url is not a network URL, it will be loaded with loadUrl(String)
>   instead.

How would I find the actual implementation code for both methods, because I do not understand the meaning of network URL. I have looked at the `WebView` code but that refers to another method which I cannot find the implementation of...

I am assuming the difference between the two methods is, one is POST and the other one is GET..., and, if this is the case, under which condition will Android switch between the two automatically as the description indicates.

Thanks,

Andreas

Comment: Found my answer:     public void postUrl(String url, byte[] postData) {
        if (URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url)) {
            switchOutDrawHistory();
            WebViewCore.PostUrlData arg = new WebViewCore.PostUrlData();
            arg.mUrl = url;
            arg.mPostData = postData;
            mWebViewCore.sendMessage(EventHub.POST_URL, arg);
            clearHelpers();
        } else {
            loadUrlImpl(url);
        }
    }

Comment: public static boolean isNetworkUrl(String url) {
        if (url == null || url.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return isHttpUrl(url) || isHttpsUrl(url);
    }